# Python re.sub() weirdness

Tags: python, regex

I'm very new to Python, in fact this is my first script.

I'm struggling with Python's regular expressions. Specifically `re.sub()`

I have the following code:

```
variableTest = "192"
test = re.sub(r'(\$\{\d{1,2}\:)example.com(\})', r'\1' + variableTest + r'\2', searchString, re.M )
```

With this I'm trying to match something like `host": "${9:example.com}"` within `searchString` and replace `example.com` with a server name or IP address.

If `variableTest` contains an IP, it fails. I get the following error:
`sre_constants.error: invalid group reference`

I've tested it with `variableTest` equal to "127.0.0.1", "1", "192", "192.168". "127.0.0.1" works while the rest doesn't. If I prepend the others with a letter it also works.

`variableTest` is a string - verified with `type(variableTest)`

I'm totally lost as to why this is.

If I remove `r'\1'` in the replacement string it also works. `r'\1'` will containt `${\d}:`, with `\d` a number between 1 and 999.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please note that while nneonneo's post gives you the actual answer to your problem, PurityLake's remark about your command call is also true: you are actually setting the optional argument `count` with the flag `re.M`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that putting an IP in `variableTest` will result in a replacement string like this:

```
r'\18.8.8.8\2'
```

As you can see, the first group reference is to group 18, not group 1. Hence, `re` complains about the invalid group reference.

In this case, you want to use the [`\g<n>` syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) instead:

```
r'\g<1>' + variableTest + r'\g<2>'
```

which produces e.g. `r'\g<1>8.8.8.8\g<2>'`.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much! Python's regex is strange :) I'll read up further on the linked syntax.

Answer (score 1):

re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

This is the syntax for re.sub()

The way you seem to be calling the flag re.M, should be like flags=re.M, otherwise python will take it as if you mean that count=re.M

give it a try as it is the only thing i can decide

also give me an example of what your searchString variable might contain

Comment: When I use `flags=re.M` instead of just `re.M` I get the following error "sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'"

`test = re.sub(r'(\$\{\d{1,2}\:)example.com(\})', r'\1' + variableTest + r'\2', searchString, flags=re.M )`

Comment: The optional input argument `flags` in `re.sub` was introduced in Python 2.7. The error message you get probably comes up because you are using a previous version of Python. Check [re.compile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) for more details on the usage of `re.M`